# Card.io - Cancel Button tint color

Tags: card.io

How can I set the cancel button tint color?

I've tried setting navigationBarStyle and navigationBarTintColor, but those don't change that.

Thanks.

[image: Scan view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@fernandospr use UIAppearance prior to presenting the `CardIOPaymentViewController`.

Like this:

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[CardIOPaymentViewController class], nil] setTintColor:specialColor];`